# Conan & CMake & VSCode ClangD: goto definition works, but goto implementation not (and impl docs not available)

Tags: c++, cmake, conan, clangd

##### Problem

I installed [ftxui](https://github.com/ArthurSonzogni/FTXUI/tree/main) into my CMake managed project using [canon](https://conan.io/), and I'm using [vscode-clangd](https://github.com/clangd/vscode-clangd.git) (I'll call it clangd) as the LSP. However, I found that clangd provided "hover to view document" to be "not useful" and go to implementation "founds none".

After some research I found that the author of ftxui split their source code into `hpp` (declaration) and `cpp` (implementation) files, but the actual docs are written in the `cpp` files. And conan stores them in different locations: `cpp`s are under `~/.conan2/p/b/ftxuif8e789ccd8656/b/src/src/ftxui` and `hpp`s are under `~/.conan2/p/b/ftxuif8e789ccd8656/b/src/include/ftxui`. However, clangd used `~/.conan2/p/b/ftxuif8e789ccd8656/p/include/ftxui` to provide docs and completions and all I found under this dir are `hpp`s. But I noticed that `~/.conan2/p/b/ftxuif8e789ccd8656/p/lib` stores some compiled libraries with `.a` as their file extension.

I assumed the string after `ftxui` to be hash, because I downloaded the library several times and found several different dirs with same prefix.

##### Expectation

I would like clangd to provide the actual documentation written in the `cpp` files when I hover over an item, and it being able to perform "go to implementation". Or, if this it not possible, understand why and knows where to open an issue (or accept the fact).

##### Supplementary

As far as I know, clangd uses the `compile_commands.json` generated by CMake to provide IntelliSense, do I need to set some CMake build flags?

- [The project I have question with](https://github.com/Saplyn/lyn-lab) (just a starter project copied from [the tutorial](https://arthursonzogni.github.io/FTXUI/index.html))
- I'm using Ubuntu 22.04, Conan v2.1.0, CMake v3.28.3, clangd v18.1.2 and gcc v11.4.0
- My VSCode uses clangd as the LSP and have disabled [cpptools](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools.git) plugin.

##### Misc

I'm unsure if this is a problem of mine, or clangd (or vscode-clangd), or conan, or the library author. So any guidance, help and clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No code intellisense engine will dig into the source of a compiled library as far as I'm aware, they all only work off the header files

Comment: You should submit a bug to ftxui. Documentation comments should be in headers.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, thanks! So do doc comments always belong to header file (in c & cpp)? (also, should I mark your comment to be the answer?)

Comment: *"always belong to header file"* Yep, I think so. I'm ok with you posting the answer.

Comment: This is not related to Conan. Any project using a compiled library as dependency (``find_package()`` in CMake), won't be able to navigate to the .cpp sources of the dependency. Many times, the sources of the dependencies won't even be there at all, if the dependency was installed from pre-compiled binaries, as Conan often does.

Answer (score 1):

Two things would be needed to get this to work:

1. **Clangd needs to know where the source files of the library are.** This basically means, the `compile_commands.json` file for your project needs to have entries for files such as, for example, `ftxui/src/ftxui/dom /linear_gradient.cpp`. This probably doesn't happen by default, but you could make it happen with a bit of work:

   - Use ftxui's own build system to generate a `compile_commands.json` for the ftxui sources.
   - Use a json manipulation tool like [jq](https://github.com/jqlang/jq) to merge ftxui's `compile_commands.json` into your project's `compile_commands.json` (or just copy the entries from one to the other manually).
2. **Clangd needs to show hover information from comments in implementation files.** This is currently a missing feature of clangd, however there is an open PR for it: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/pull/67802. So it could get this feature soon.